# Changing ifstream to Integers (after being loaded from a .txt file) C++

Tags: c++

Okay, so, I have a couple text files that are written to and read from in my program, they are loaded using:
*here is one of the four*

```
ifstream xps;
```

and then loaded using:

```
xps.open ("xp.txt", fstream::in | fstream::app);
```

Inside of xps is a number, and I would an integer (called xp) to load this number.

So how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you just want to read the integer from the file? If so, all you have to do is use `operator >>` from the `ifstream` class:

```
int xp;
xps >> xp;
```

And then xp will hold the number from the file.

You can do the same thing with different types as well, such as `char`s, `float`s, `string`s, etc.